# Disprove Division Statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

I tried to disprove the statement below. Are my steps valid?

Let **a, b** and **c** be positive integers.

Disprove: $$c \nmid b \implies c \nmid (2a + 7b)  \lor c \nmid(a - b)$$

Goal: Provide a case where the premise is true but the conclusion is false.

**My Proof:**

Consider when a=4, b=1, and c=3.

Then $$3 \nmid 1$$ is true, and $$3 \nmid 15 \lor 3 \nmid 3 $$ is false.
Showing that there is a case where assuming $$c \nmid b $$ leads to a false conclusion.

If my steps are valid, **how can I improve my wording / organization of the proof?**

Is there a better way to come up with values for a, b, and c other than brute-force?

Comment: Prove the contrapositive

Comment: But is this way valid as well? You mean show c divides (2a + 7b) and c divides (a - b) implies c divides b? But how is that disproving?